# What is a good statistical test to use to compare 2 models

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, statistical-inference, bayesian, hypothesis-testing

I have already posted this question on Stats stackexchange so I am unsure whether I am allowed to post it here to.

I am asking what would be a good/suitable investigation/test to use when trying to compare 2 models.

So for my model in question, I am looking at the Lac Operon model and I add in substace $Y$ into the model and it produces enzyme $X$. The objective of adding $Y$ into the system is the produce as much $X$ as possible. I want to investigate if it is better to add all my $Y$ into the system in one big go (let's say I add 10,000 in all together), or to add say 2,000 $Y$ in at 5 even time intervals, or to add 1,000 of $Y$ in in 10 even time intervals.

I am wondering what sort of statistical analysis should i be using here, or what sort of tests should I be performing.  I know I could just look at the amount of $X$ produced for each variation of my model, but I am looking for more intricate tests to perform.

Now my models aren't linear models so I am unable to do anova using `R`, they are actually stochastic models. They are a series of chemical equations but I am basically just interested in the value of $X$, so i doubt the specifics of the model are needed to be known.

Edit: May I propose another question to you. So to follow on from my earlier point, basically I have a system of chemical equations, and the rate constants from these equations follow a gamma distribution. Should I be testing rate constants against each other, or should I be testing the data against each other?

Edit: Maybe I could test the comparison of the rate constants for my 2 models by using Bayesian Inference? I was wondering what would be a suitable test to compare to posterior/prior distributions rather than just using Bayes Factors??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have Methods A and B of producing $X.$ If you have $n_1$ 
independent runs with Method A, and independently of that you have $n_2$
runs with method B. Also suppose that the amount of $X$ produced by each
method is approximately normal. Say $X_{ai} \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu_a, \sigma_a)$
and $X_{bi} \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu_b, \sigma_b).$

Then you want to test $H_0: \mu_a = \mu_b$ against $H_1: \mu_a \ne \mu_b.$
The appropriate test would be the Welch (separate-variances) two-sample t test.

Supposing that data are far from normal, but that the distributions for
A and B are of the same shape, then the Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon rank-sum
test could be used to see if there is a shift in the location of the *median*
$\eta_a$ of Method A to $\eta_b \ne \eta_a$ for Method B. If the assumptions for
this test are not met (or if there are many tied values among the two samples
of $X$'s), then you could see if a permutation test is useful.

Not knowing how many observations you would have for each method, and not
knowing the shapes of the population distributions I could not give a useful
opinion which kind of test to use.

*Note:* If 'batches' to which methods are applied differ greatly, then
it might be a good idea to split each batch in two, and to use Method A
on one half and Method B on the other. Then you might have $n$ pairs of
of outputs $X$. For this experimental design, a paired t test, a Wilcoxon signed-rank test, or a
paired permutation test might be more likely to find any difference
between methods.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. May I propose another question to you. So to follow on from my earlier point, basically I have a system of chemical equations, and the rate constants from these equations follow a gamma distribution. Should I be testing rate constants against each other, or should I be testing the data against each other?

Comment: Sorry to double comment, but I get the using of Welch test, but to follow on from this suppose that the means are significantly different, could I then just say the test which has the higher mean is the better one?? Also as I'm doing 5000 repetitions I don't need to use the t-test do I?

Comment: If the P-value of the Welch test is smaller than about 2.5%, you should take the method with the larger sample mean to be the one with the larger population mean. Anytime population variance(s) unknown, it's a t test; sample size is irrelevant to that. (For n = 5000, the critical value will be about 1.96, but are still est pop var with sample var.

Comment: Yeah I get you. I think I'm going to have a problem simulating my system 5000 times tho lol, it takes about half an hour to do 50. Also, do you have any comment on my edits to the original post about comparing prior/posteriors?

Comment: Are you sure you need 5000? Where did that number come from?

Comment: Well I said 5000 originally because I want to show that my data is normal. And if I do 5000 repetitions I can do the PMF for a certain species at a certain time and it should have a normal distribution

Comment: 1000 should be plenty to check normality. Demo: `set.seed(326); x = rnorm(1000,100,15); shapiro.test(x)` generates & tests 1000 normals, P-val .8. By contrast, `set.seed(327); y = rgamma(1000, 20, .1); shapiro.test(y)` for gammas. Histogram looks aprx norm, but slightly skewed. P-value is tiny (soundly rejecting normality null hypothesis). Maybe do a reality check when you have 500 or 1000, then see if you need more.

Comment: I'll run this for 1000 but will take a while. I was just wondering if you knew about any statistical tests for comparing prior/posteriors

Comment: Will have to think about Bayesian approach first. Full day of errands today and first class of spring tomorrow. I am more familiar with Bayesian CIs than Bayes factors.

Comment: That's chill man. I really appreciate your help. This is for a report I'm doing and I've already used Bayes factors earlier on, so I dont want to go back to using them

Comment: Hey, was just wondering what you thought of this Bayesian approach. If I looked at the difference in the standard deviation/ variation/ mean of the rate constants for my reactions?

Comment: What is the motivation for a Bayesian approach? Do you have a prior opinion that one of the Methods is better than the other? I guess you will have better luck with your bounty if you provide rationale and context.

Comment: So my Bayesian approach is that I have 2 very similar models but slightly different. I will have the same prior opinion, but after observing data for BOTH models, I want to compare them. Now the way I want to compare them is the problem. What I have thought is that I should look at the mean/variance/SD of my posterior distribution and compare them?

Comment: Hey man. I am going to award you the bounty, but I was wondering if you had a thought about the Bayesian approach? If not it is cool.